# How to completely disable a custom module

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, module, extensions, ce-1.6.2.0

After a week of full hard work and coding i have successfully developed a magento extension which is working as expected but when i disable the module from magento admin config it still overriding the functionality, i have read about setting false in module global config files but don't getting how can i do this programatically.

Any one have any idea how this can be solve ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the admin section with all the modules you cannot disable a module. From there you can only disable the output of some module. This means that the code is still executed but no output is generated.
Indeed,  the way to disable a module is to change the tag `<active>` to `false` in the module declaration xml (`app/etc/modules/Namespace_Module.xml`) and clear the cache.
I don't think you can disable a module from code since the modules are loaded very early in the application (`Mage_Core_Model_Config::_loadDeclaredModules()`).
When building custom modules I also like to be able to disable them with 'one click'. Here is how I usually do it:
 - add in the system.xml an 'enabled' field.

```
<enabled translate="label" module="news">
    <label>Module is enabled</label>
    <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
    <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</enabled>
```

-  create a method in the helper to check this flag

```
public function getIsEnabled(){
    return Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('section/group/enabled'); //replace section & group with appropriate values.
}
```

Now in every piece of code that is overriding something in the core or is supposed to output something, I use this helper method.
Let's say you are overriding a method called `getSomething()` in a class. This is how your method should look like:

```
function getSomething($params){
    if (!Mage::helper('module_name')->getIsEnabled()){ //if my module is not enabled
        return parent::getSomething($params);
    }
    //your logic here.
}
```

Every `.phtml` in your module should look like this:

```
<?php if (Mage::helper('module_name')->getIsEnabled()) : //if my module is enabled?>
    <div>Block output here</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If all your template and overwritten methods look like this, you should be able to disable (simulate disable) from the configuration panel.

Comment: Thanks man for detailed explanation , but get disappointed i can't disable it permanently the code still executes.. :-(

Comment: @Marius, if my module has a URL that shows custom listing, then even if I disable the module, it will still show the listing and 404 page not found.

Comment: @Vikram. I don't understand. add a question related to this and explain what is the problem. Screenshots can help also.

Answer (score 8):

Marius is quite right except one thing.

Even disabling module by setting `active` to false in the bootstrap file is not enough in case some other module is extending it's class or using it's template.

So to be 100% sure the extension is disabled you also have to remove it's all files or at least rename directories/files.

Comment: Right. Thanks Tim. Even if the chance is small of this happening it still exists. That's why you should declare the dependencies int the bootstrap file. That way if you disable a module by setting `active` to false and an other module depends on the one you just deactivated, you should get an error and realize what's wrong.

Comment: @Marius : absolutely right.